# Running Rational Robot scripts without Robot installed

Tags: deployment, scripting, automation, ibm-rational

I have a Rational Robot script that I would like to deploy to multiple workstations. I wanted to know if there is a way to run this script without having Robot installed on those workstations. As you may know, Robot licenses are expensive so I only have one license available for development.

Is there any way to perhaps run it as an executable? Any other ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a way to run Robot scripts as standalone executables, but there is a product called the IBM Rational Agent Controller that allows you to distribute Robot scripts to remote systems without installing Robot on them.  The systems running the Agent Controller do not require a full license of Robot - they simply enable script playback.  More details about the Agent Controller can be found here:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27013420